# How much will damage increase after perfect reload, and will it increase elemental damage?

Tags: mercenary-kings

When you're reloading your weapon, if you hit reload on the green area it will be "perfect reload" and your ammo will start to glow. One of the Tribute Games staff members [said](http://tributegames.com/forum/showthread.php?tid=1910) that perfect reload will give you a small damage boost.

What i want to know is how small that boost actually is, and does it only increases POW of the weapon or elemental damage as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boost is an additional 10% weapon power (no effect on elemental damage). Lasts for the corresponding number of bullets in the reload.